# Possible to modify the contents of a WSP through code?

Tags: visual-studio, solution-package

I have a base WSP and I would like to create an automated process to update one of the files that it contains (an XML file).

Is there anything in the Object Model that would allow me to do this?  If not is there some way I could treat it as a CAB file and then modify the contents using standard .NET?

If I can't do either of the above, is it possible to recompile the project that creates the WSP through code and pass it a parameter that would implement the change?

Comment: Can you elaborate - are you looking to update something after packaging and before deployment (e.g. a version number or something)?

Comment: I have an XML file that I plan on putting a license key into.  Basically I am making an application that will generate the key, update the xml file and then email out the wsp to whoever purchased the key.

Comment: Abe, why don't you use a separate xml file for that? Simple upload the licence file via web UI or via configuration/deployment script later. That's exactly how Nintex does. Why not?

Answer (score 2):

Given that you're updating an XML file with a License Key this is what I would do.

(realise that a .wsp is just a renamed .cab file and that most zip software can unzip cab as well).

- Use the EXPAND cmd line tool to unpack the .wsp to a local folder

*(EDIT - Cabinet SDK and Expand tool no longer available. Instead use 7-Zip and http://ddfgenerator.codeplex.com/ - see bottom link)*

- Change the .xml file using whatever method appropriate
- Rebuild the .wsp file using MAKECAB

[KB176810 - How To Manually Modify and Rebuild CAB Files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176810)

[Rebuilding a .WSP File in 4 Easy Steps](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2010/02/16/rebuilding-a-.wsp-file-in-4-easy-steps.aspx)

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?  I was exploring this possibility before but I came across this post: http://sharepointroot.com/2010/07/07/editing-contents-of-a-wsp-sharepoint/  which seems to suggest that modifying a WSP in this way is not easily done.  I haven't tried it myself though...

Comment: Yes - its fiddly to get right but by no means impossible.

Comment: Sweet, I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Turns out I somehow had a copy of expand which I can't find any more (this is part of the withdrawn makecab sdk) - for alternative see "Rebuilding" link which has copy of DDF generator on codeplex

Answer (score 2):

You could use the WSPBuilder project from codeplex (http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com) to open up the WSP and modify any of the consisting files. WSPs can be opened up, modified and repackaged through the command line.  More details at: http://www.itmonotony.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=40

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.SE! We  require relevant answers and disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You dont specify the business case behind your requirement, but it sounds like something i would use web part adder for.

With this little known gem you can provision web parts dynamically, essentially as if you had several xml webpart files.

Read more in Wictor Wilen's blog post series on the [subject](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Dynamically-populate-the-Web-Part-Gallery-using-the-WebPartAdder-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx).

Comment: Basically I have an XML file that I plan on putting a license key into. I am making an application that will generate the key, update the xml file and then email out the wsp to whoever purchased the key.

Comment: With web part adder you could Have a central key repository instead, this would probably give you more control. If you go the xml way, you will probably want to disable export or at least protect the license key against being exported

Comment: The application that will be modifying the WSP will not be a SharePoint application.  Just a standalone ASP.NET web application.  Would this solution still work?

Comment: Did you read the blog posts i mentioned? You are not modifying WSP's at all, you are using code and (for example) a data source of some kind to dynamically populate a web part group.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are saying.  I did read the post you mentioned.  When you say "You are not modifying WSP's at all" are you saying I don't NEED to modify a WSP in order do what I am trying to acheive?  As it is right now I am definitely modifying a WSP.

Comment: The article describe how to dynamically set a web part property for several instances of the same web part. So basically you set (here) the productID property for each productID in the list, instead of having 3 web parts, you only have one and values are set programmatically. So you need only one WSP instead of 3 modified WSPs

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
>   I have a base WSP and I would like to create an automated process to update one of the files that it contains (an XML file).

Okay, as far as I saw prev posts, I would recommend to separate licence file and build up a web interface or bat/powershell script to setup licence file later. Exactly like Nintex workflow or other products does.

Personally, I don't think modifying wsp package is a appropriate strategy in that case.